# Webpack and node externals

Tags: angular, webpack, node-modules, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to use universal angular v4 specifically this template.

https://github.com/FrozenPandaz/ng-universal-demo/tree/master/src

Among the modules I use are @ngrx \ store and @ngrx \ effects, to name a few.
I follow the default configuration, except that in node modules I have added the following

```
externals:[
       nodeExternals ({
       modulesFromFile: true,
     })
]
```

I use it to be able to use libraries like mongoose, among others.

I'm trying to use the compilation with aot, however I get the following error[image]

Supposedly there is a solution in the following link, but I can not implement it

https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/387

My final externals is

```
externals: [
includeClientPackages(/@angularclass|@angular|@angular\/core|angular2-|ng2-|ng-|@ng-|angular-|ngrx-|@angular2|ionic|@ionic|-angular2|-ng2|-ng/),
   nodeExternals({
      modulesFromFile: true,
    })
]
```

But I have the same error, I would appreciate any possible help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `includeClientPackages` or `nodeExternals` with a whitelist. Using both will not work.

I solved this bug using the following in my webpack config:

```
    externals: [
      webpackNodeExternals({
        whitelist: [ /@ngrx/ ]
      })
    ]
```